# How do I make my website responsive using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a newbie making a website. The website shows perfect on big screens but its layout gets jumbled up on smaller screens. Can someone please help me out with what I'm doing wrong? How can I fix it? 
Thank you so much.

Here is My Code and Link to my website.

**Link:** 
https://luckdrum.herokuapp.com/index.html

**Code**

```
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->


    <title>LuckDrum</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/fav.ico" />
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="css/bootstrap.css" >

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="jumbotron.css">


  </head>

  <body>

    <!--Heading Formation-->
 <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

<h5 align="left"><a href="#">PEOPE SEARCH</a></h5>
<!---->
<h6 class="text-center"><a href="#"></a>PEOPLE-THINGS RECOMENDATION</h6>

<h6 id="h12"><a href="#"></a>Actors/movies</h6>
<h6 id="h13" class="text-center"><a href="#"></a>Authors</h6>
<h6 id="h14"class="text-center"><a href="#"></a>Chefs</h6>
<h6 id="h15"class="text-right"><a href="#"></a>Designers</h6>
<h6 id="h16"class="text-center"><a href="#"></a>Handcrafters</h6>
<h6 id="h17"><a href="#"></a>Jewelers</h6>
<h6 id="h18"><a href="#"></a>Musicans</h6>
<h6 id="h19"><a href="#"></a>Painters</h6>
<h6 id="h20"><a href="#"></a>Singers</h6>
<h6 id="h21"><a href="#"></a>Winemaker</h6>
<h6 id="h22"><a href="#"></a>Architect</h6>
<h6 id="h23"><a href="#"></a>bloggers</h6>
<h6 id="h24"><a href="#"></a>Hosts</h6>
<h6 id="h25"><a href="#"></a>Infographers</h6> 
    </div>
</div>
    </div></body>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using any Bootstrap grid system CSS classes on your elements. Please see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: It's very important to understand the mobile first design of bootstrap before you start coding.

Comment: @Stack0verflow  please help me what should i do for placing the headers in order like shown in link? Should i use different approach for making?

Comment: @IndieRok Yeah i am Following you , thank you man. You mean i should used col-xs-12 for viewing it on the device view-port?

Comment: It depends on how many columns *YOU* want on an extremely small screen. If you want 12 columns, go for it.

Comment: Well, it actually depends on what layout you are going for. It's not always that, you see

Comment: @Stack0verflow I need to make 6 columns and place headers there.

Comment: @IndieRok i need to make 6 columns and adjust my headers in it. And make them responsive. Should i use like <div class=container><div class="column"><div class="col-md-6"><h6>Hello</h6></div>.....

Comment: @CameronTinker  i need to make 6 columns and adjust my headers in it. And make them responsive. Should i use like <div class=container><div class="column"><div class="col-md-6"><h6>Hello</h6></div>...

Comment: <div class="column"> doesn't exists in bootstrap. I think you should go and learn the basics before trying anything else. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Yeah Sorry Its <div class="row"> . ^EDITED

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap works on a `col-*` grid system with designated breakpoints that depend on the viewport size. The `col-*` sizes are set to break at specific widths on that viewport.

Here are the standard Bootstrap v3.3.5 media queries that corresponds with the documentation that outlines the responsive classes that are available.

```
/* Extra Small Devices, .visible-xs-* */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {}

    /* Small Devices, .visible-sm-* */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}

    /* Medium Devices, .visible-md-* */
    @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {}

    /* Large Devices, .visible-lg-* */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Below is an example of an acceptable bootstrap layout, note it looks nothing like yours currently,

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
     <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/GpBzPP?editors=110)